# Color property not applying on textview in new android studio 2.2

Tags: android, colors, android-studio-2.2

I have recently installed the new version of android studio (ver 2.2). I have given color changing property to my textviews in my project. which were working fine in the previous version of android studio. But in new version the color properties are only applied in the design view of android studio. But when i run my app, i saw default black color textviews.

My colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="clrlightblue">#59a9de</color>
    <color name="clrblue">#6b72f9</color>
    <color name="clrwhite">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="clrblack">#000000</color>
    <color name="clrlightyellow">#fcfbe3</color>
</resources>
```

A textview:

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add  Contacts"
            android:onClick="addMoreContacts"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textColor="@color/clrwhite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextEtype"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextEtype"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewRepeat"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewRepeat" />
```

As the color is changed to white, In Design view it is looking white. But after running the app its color is black. Please help me if anyone have the solution. Thank you!

Comment: try to uninstall old build and install new one.

Comment: @Harshid it is still not working...

Comment: @WaqasKhan kindly see my answer below and reply.

Answer (score 0):

i am using 2.2 Preview 6 even on previous previews it worked right.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText_userName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cloud Tech."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
```

And color in values/colors.xml

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

[image]

Device tested MotoG (2nd Gen - 6.0)

Some suggestions - clean your project, rebuilt it and then see what it displays.

Comment: i am also working on preview6. i tried it but still having same problem. text color is still black

Comment: although in design view the text color is white. but when i run the app, it shows black color in the app

Comment: you have set invisible on textview from xml so you are trying to make it visible from java code? change its color too while changing its visibility, will work. clean, rebuild, didn't help ?

Comment: visibility is not the issue. problem comes with changing text color. i am using different colors for textviews and i have the same issue every where in my project..

Comment: Post your Activity code as well which is using above xml

Comment: Is this issue also bothering you in other projects, as well?